# Using JTable - specifying size

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using a JTable in a program. The problem is that when I set the size of the whole JTable, I am using this method:

```
setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(Dimension size)
```

The question I have is that when using this method, you enter in the width and length in pixels. Will there be issues (formatting-wise) when the program is run on different computers/machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) - Short answer is yes (you should avoid it)

When setting the preferredSize of the table, you are not actually taking into account the number of rows or columns which the table might have, depending on the layout manager, it may NEVER be larger than the dimensions you provide, regardless of the amount of data

> The question I have is that when using this method, you enter in the width and length in pixels. Will there be issues (formatting-wise) when the program is run on different computers/machines?

Generally, yes.

`JTable` was designed to be shown within a `JScrollPane`, which allows you some leeway with this, as the `JTable` can grow and shrink, within the `JScrollPane`, but the `JScrollPane` can remain the same.

Having said that, you should NOT be using `setPreferredSize` and especially not messing with `JTable`s, `JTable` calculates it's own preferred size based on the needs of the data...and it does a reasonably good job.

If you want to change the size the `JScrollPane`, then you will need to change the result of [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()) which lets the `JScrollPane` know how big a component would like the basic viewable area to be, under optimal conditions

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: So if this is the case, what should I use to set the size of the JTable?

Comment: @noobProgrammer Generally, you should do anything.  You can use layout managers appropriately; you should be using a `JScrollPane` to display the `JTable`

Comment: Did you put it in a `JScrollPane`?  Did you adjust the `weightx`/`weighty` and/or `ipadx`/`ipady` properties of `GridBagConstraints`?